# Jms: Pub/Sub with mutiple consumers

Tags: spring-boot, jms, oracle-aq

For JMS pub/sub with a topic and two durable subscribers, in most cases when a message is sent to the topic we want the message to be consumed by both subscribers.

But in a particular scenario we may want want the message to be consumed by only a particular subscriber. Is that possible and can it be done? We are using OracleAQ with Spring Boot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use message selectors.

Simply add a property to the message that you then filter in the consumer.

Producer

```
Message msg = ...

// Setting message properties
msg.setStringProperty("releaseYear", "1977");
```

Consumer

```
MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(queue, "releaseYear < 1980");
```

Read more here:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/ois.817/a65435/jms_feat.htm#1001827